# (Quicksight) Is it possible to have a claculated field that takes date field granularity into account

Tags: business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

**Context:** I have an dataset of Orders in quicksight, that is joined with Customer data.  Because a Customer can have more than one Order the Customer data is duplicated and needs to be deduped.

I need to do an analysis of the number of days it took from the Customer to register (`customer_date_added`) to their first order (`min(order_date_added)`) and then bucket/group the results based on customer_date_added with different granularities of the date.

This is what I currently have working (6 visuals corresponding to the built-in date granularities in quicksight: year, quarter, month, week, day, hour)

```
    *Visual 1* - x-axis:customer_date_added (aggregate year), y-axis: 
    ifelse(dateDiff(customer_date_added, min(order_date_added)) < 365, 1, 0)
    
    *Visual 2* - x-axis:customer_date_added (aggregate quarter), y-axis: 
    ifelse(dateDiff(customer_date_added, min(order_date_added)) < 90, 1, 0)
    
    *Visual 3* - x-axis:customer_date_added (aggregate month), y-axis: 
    ifelse(dateDiff(customer_date_added, min(order_date_added)) < 30, 1, 0)
    
    *Visual 4* - x-axis:customer_date_added (aggregate week), y-axis: 
    ifelse(dateDiff(customer_date_added, min(order_date_added)) < 7, 1, 0)
```

.... etc

**Issue:** I have a lot of these dateDiff with bucketing visuals (not just days to first order) so my field list is getting overrun with fields like `customer_first_order_within_year`, `customer_first_order_within_quarter`, `customer_first_order_within_month`, etc.  Also rather than just have one visual where I can change the date_granularity from year to month I have to maintain 6 different visuals for each dateDiff analysis I want to to.

**What I want:**  One visual with two calculated fields (`new_customer_with_first_order`, `new_customer_no_first_order`).  When I change the data granularity on customer_date_added to a new date granularity, the `new_customer_with_first_order` automatically displays customers that were added in that time period AND with a first order within that time period.  Conversely `new_customer_no_first_order` would display customers that were added in that time period AND did not have an order within that time period.  `new_customer_with_first_order + new_customer_no_first_order = new customers within that time period`.

**What I have tried:** I am relatively new to quicksight and business intelligence tools, but have a pretty good grasp of SQL. I have tried to read up on Level Aware Aggregation, Window Functions.  None of these give examples using dates or date granularity.  This seems like it would be a popular type of analysis but maybe it's not possible yet?

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63064505/3412268
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/windowMax-function.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/countOver-function.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/level-aware-aggregations.html
```