# QuickSight count new invoiced users per month

Tags: amazon-quicksight

My dataset is a list of user invoices.

I can easily show how many invoices I have per month (aggregate the invoice date per month).

Now how can I show per month how many new users are invoiced?

Let's say I have the following data

| invoice_id | user_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Oct |
| 2 | 1 | Nov |
| 3 | 2 | Nov |

I have 1 invoice in October and 2 in November.

I have 1 new invoiced user in October and 1 new invoiced user in November.

Edit: Basically I would like to filter out invoices and keep only the first one for each user.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [difference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/difference-function.html) calculated field, from your example I think I can get what you mean, I can make a table like the following

| date | difference | count(user_id) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Oct |  | 1 |
| Nov | 1 | 2 |

Using the following formula:

```
difference
(
     count({user_id}),
     [ {date} ASC ],
     1
)
```

I realize this skips out the 1 for October but this should only happen for the first month that the analysis shows

Comment: Ok I see what you mean there. Basically it calculates the variation of total users invoiced month by month.
That works fine, in my question though I was more interested into the number of new users only, excluding those who are not invoiced anymore. It's slightly different.

Comment: Yes I see the difference, your own answer is much better

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to find a way thanks to @occamatic and another answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170840/quicksight-how-to-sum-values-only-from-unique-fields):

I can add a calculated field like `is_first_invoice`:

```
ifelse( minOver({date}, [{user_id}] , PRE_AGG) = {date}, 1, 0)
```

Then in my analysis I add a filter to exclude 0 values for this field. I am left with only first invoices.