# How to calculate sum distinct in quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, calculated-field

| Partner | UserID | Marks | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 | AM |
| A | 2 | 7 | AM |
| A | 1 | 4 | AM |
| B | 3 | 5 | CM |
| C | 4 | 6 | TM |
| B | 3 | 5 | CM |

I want to calculate sum of 'Marks' for each partner excluding double rows.

I've tried (sum(maxOver(Marks, [UserID, Partner], PRE_AGG))). But it's giving me a table like :

| Partner | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| A | 15 |
| B | 10 |
| C | 6 |

Whereas, I want a table as below :

| Partner | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| A | 11 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 6 |

Thank you for your help, cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Quicksight) How to Sum Values only from Unique Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170840/quicksight-how-to-sum-values-only-from-unique-fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated field with a countOver() function to detect the duplicate rows, and then use it as a filter in a sumIf() function.
Example:

```
sumIf({Marks},countOver({Marks,[{Partner},{UserID},{Marks},{Group}],PRE_AGG)=1)
```